# C++ Function Pointer in C# DLL

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I have a C++ DLL calling a C# DLL via COM. When I initialize my C# DLL I’d like to pass in a callback function. I seem to be getting random crashes. Can someone explain what I’m doing wrong?

C++

communications.h

```
#import "ultra_comm.tlb"

typedef void(*ExternalKickPtr)(const char*, const char*);

class UltraComm
{

public
:
    void Initialize(ExternalKickPtr kick);
private:
    ultra_comm::ICOMPtr iCOM;
};
```

communications.cpp

```
#include "communications.h"

void UltraComm::Initialize(ExternalKickPtr kick)
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    iCOM.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ultra_comm::Communications));

    iCOM->Initialize((long)kick);   **<-- this seems to be where it crashes**
}
```

ultra_css.h

```
void ExternalKickFunc(const char* steamId, const char* message);

ultra_css.cpp
UltraComm* ultra = NULL;

ultra = new UltraComm();
if(ultra)
{
ultra->Initialize(&ExternalKickFunc);
}
```

C#

Communications.cs

```
namespace Ultra_Comm
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("DAB7E676-44B4-4D3E-947A-7D9369AE2D43")]
    public interface ICOM
    {
        void Initialize(IntPtr kick);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("DFC77C60-945E-4712-AE2F-DCF5379BA83B")]
    public class Communications : ICOM, IWCF
    {
        delegate void FuncKickPlayer(string steamId, string message);

        static FuncKickPlayer _kick;

        public void Initialize(IntPtr kick)
        {
            _kick = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(kick, typeof(FuncKickPlayer)) as FuncKickPlayer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is pretty unclear how you got this to run even once.  The delegate declaration doesn't match the function pointer type, the delegate is __stdcall but the function pointer is __cdecl.  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] is required on the delegate declaration.  The better way to do this is to just make the callback a COM interface as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans. It’s pretty unclear to me also, that’s why I’m asking the question. I changed my code to this
`void Initialize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]IntPtr kick);`
but it’s still crashing. Can you explain what you mean by making the callback a COM interface or better yet give an example?

Comment: Why would you, in this day and age, cast a pointer into `long` instead of `intptr_t` or `INT_PTR`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Medinoc, that worked. I was casting it to long because that was the signature in the .tlb file. This also worked `iCOM->Initialize(reinterpret_cast<long>(kick));` but I like your idea better `iCOM->Initialize((intptr_t)kick);`